# Angular (8) Http.post() is giving SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Tags: json, angular

When I try post data to my server, I'm getting the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse...
```

I am not using JSON.parse() so I assume Angulars Http.post() automatically does this?

When I try console.log(JSON.parse(data)), I'm getting:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1...
```

When I send the data from Postman - works perfectly fine, no errors and the server receives it.

When I send the data in a fetch() api request - also works perfectly fine, no errors whatsoever.

So, this only occurs when I try use angulars HTTP lib and try to post. 
Below is an example of some JSON data I send and an example of my http post.

Thanks in advance! This has been driving me crazy!

```
{"tutorialName":"cvbcvbxcvbxcvbbxcv","sections":[]}
```

```js
this.http.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/endpoint", JSON.stringify(this.tutorialForm.value)).subscribe();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTPClient POST tries to parse a non-JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826531/httpclient-post-tries-to-parse-a-non-json-response)

Comment: You either have to set the response type in angular side this way `responseType: 'text'` or on the server side encode the data as json

Comment: @Ale8k  can you post  response as well to find out where you have  got error in response.

Comment: Yeah sure will try now

Ok, so I sent  JSON response back from the server and it was happy, which header to I need to add to my post to expect a status in Angular? Thank you so much @Sanoj_V

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the solution was the response type option on HTTP.post in Angular, it didn't align up with the server (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType for types) and defaults to JSON. Thank you to all who answered!