# Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0 for post method in angular

Tags: javascript, java, angular, hibernate

I am getting the below error in angular my backend is java

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:10132:51)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3626:31)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73280:33)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3625:60)
>       at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3403:47)
>       at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3700:34)
>       at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4838:14)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4875:21)

bank.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Bank } from './bank';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BankService {

  private baseurl='http://localhost:8080/';

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getAllCustomers():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/allbank');
  }

  addCustomer(bank:Bank):Observable<any>{
    console.log(bank)
    return this.http.post(this.baseurl+'bank',bank);
  }

  getCustomer():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('{$this.baseurl}/bank/${id}');
  }


}
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BankService } from '../bank.service';
import { Bank } from '../bank';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-customer',
  templateUrl: './add-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-customer.component.css']
})
export class AddCustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private bankService:BankService) { }
  bank:Bank=new Bank();
  submitted=false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.submitted=false;
  }
  banksaveform=new FormGroup({
    bankcustid:new FormControl(),
    bankcustname:new FormControl(),
    bankcustbalance:new FormControl(),
    bankcustpassword:new FormControl()
  })

  saveCustomer(saveCustomer)
  {
    this.bank=new Bank();
    this.bank.cust_id=this.banksaveform.get("bankcustid").value;
    this.bank.cust_name=this.banksaveform.get("bankcustname").value;
    this.bank.cust_balance=this.banksaveform.get("bankcustbalance").value;
    this.bank.cust_password=this.banksaveform.get("bankcustpassword").value;
    this.submitted=true;
    this.save();
  }

  save()
  {
    this.bankService.addCustomer(this.bank)
    .subscribe(data=>console.log(data),error=>console.log(error));
    this.bank=new Bank();
  }

  addCustomerForm()
  {
    this.submitted=false;
    this.banksaveform.reset();
  }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTPClient POST tries to parse a non-JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826531/httpclient-post-tries-to-parse-a-non-json-response)

Comment: @saivinaymanapuram Please provide json that your client get. Please also look at [this](https://codeburst.io/angular-best-practices-4bed7ae1d0b7). You should avoid to use `any`.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you make some HTTP request and try to parse the response, but the response is not in the JSON format.

Something useful that you can do in order to hunt the source of this bug (in case you have a heavy website with a lot of outgoing requests) is to override the `JSON.parse()` `and XMLHttpRequest.open()` methods.

Place this on top of your `app.module.ts` for example :

```
// Override JSON.parse for debug purposes
(function () {
    var parse = JSON.parse;

    JSON.parse = function (str) {
        try {
            return parse.apply(this, arguments);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error parsing', arguments);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}());


// Override XMLHttpRequest.open
(function() {
    var origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        this.addEventListener('load', function() {
            console.log('Http Response', this.responseText, this);
        });
        origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();
```

When trying to parse something that is not JSON, anywhere in your code, the overwritten `JSON.parse` will leave a log.

Once you have the value of what failed to be parsed, look for a matching log from the overwritten `XMLHttpRequest.open`. Inspect the request and you will see what the URL/endpoint is.